# Differences between substitution and rewriting?

Tags: formal-languages

I am continuing with my self-study of formal languages.

Given two alphabets $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$, [a string substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_homomorphism#String_substitution) is a mapping from $\Sigma$ to $\mathcal P(\Delta^*)$, which induces a mapping from $\Sigma^*$ to $\mathcal P(\Delta^*)$.

In case that a string substitution is [a string homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_homomorphism#String_homomorphism), it  is a mapping from $\Sigma$ to $\Delta^*$, which induces a mapping from $\Sigma^*$ to $ \Delta^*$.

[A rewriting system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_rewriting_system#Example_1), however, seems to be a relation on $\Sigma^* \times \Delta^*$.

So I wonder if the main difference between rewriting and substitution is that rewriting is a relation, which might not be a mapping, while substitution is a mapping? Thanks.

Comment: Note that a mapping from $\Sigma^*$ to ${\mathcal P}(\Delta^*)$ and a relation on $\Sigma^*\times \Delta^*$ are usually considered equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

There are three differences between substitutions and rewriting systems:

1. Substitutions happen one symbol at a time, while a rewrite rule can rewrite an entire substring at once.
2. Substitution is a single-valued function while in a rewriting system, several rewriting rules can apply to any given substring.
3. A substitution must specify what value is substituted for each symbol. Rewriting systems need not apply in all situations.

I would say that the first two are the major differences. You can define substitutions so that they are partial functions, and then the third difference doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks. "Substitutions happen one symbol at a time", but they can induce a mapping that can apply to a string at a time, by concatenation?

Comment: @Tim Still, it happens one symbol at a time.

Comment: Interesting answer. I can ask this as a separate question or you can clarify in this answer. How are substitution and rewriting different with regards to commutativity and associativity? E.g. `Substitution for multiple variables does not, in general, commute.` from [nLab](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/substitution)

Comment: For those like me writing code to implement substitution and stuck on understanding `Composition of substitutions` for more detail and some examples start [here](https://slideplayer.com/slide/16671087/) on slide 7.

Comment: It's better to ask this as a separate question.